# configured apache to host pyramid app, but restarts dont show changes

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I have a pyramid application that I want to host using Apache. I started off by sucessfully getting a blank application to run - I used pyramid's starter scaffold to create a basic app then I configured apache and made sure I could see the app in my browser. It worked great - I got a nice 'welcome to pyramid' page.

Then I swapped out the code of the starter application for code that is actually useful and reloaded apache. Refreshing the page gets me back to 'welcome to pyramid'. restarting apache has the same effect.

No matter what I do Apache is running old code. How do I fix this? How do I get apache to run my actual application?

FYI...

pyramid.wsgi

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = '/home/criticalid/critical_env/pyramidapp/production.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/pyramid

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias /criticalid /home/criticalid/critical_env/pyramid.wsgi

    <Directory /home/criticalid/critical_env>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=criticalid group=criticalid threads=4 \
   python-path=/home/criticalid/critical_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my gosh. The fix is buried in the fact that I used:

```
setup.py install
```

This works a little differently...

```
setup.py develop
```